# Strange C++ string concatenation behaviour

Tags: c++, string, struct, string-concatenation

I've been noticing this strange behaviour with string concatenation despite the fact that `strcmp` returns zero, showing both forms are identical

The include file `options.h` is as follows

```
struct options = {
   std::string ctifile;
   ...
};
```

The main file is being written in two ways

Method 1

```
#include "options.h"
#include <string>
#include "cantera/IdealGasMix.h"

options opt = {
  "mech/tot.cti"
};

IdealGasMix gas(opt.ctifile, ...);
```

In the second method,

```
#include "options.h"
#include <string>
#include "cantera/IdealGasMix.h"

options opt = {
  "tot.cti"
};

IdealGasMix gas(std::string("mech/") + opt.ctifile, ...);
```

For some reason, only Method 2 is unable to find the file specified. Any pointers? (pun intended)

Comment: [No reason it shouldn't work.](http://cpp.sh/3yln)

Comment: Something else is going wrong, and it isn't clear from what you posted. You need to come up with a [mcve] that shows the issue.

Comment: Working for me. I suspect on you gas function argument declaration

Comment: Don't summarize code when you don't understand what's wrong with it. Remove some of the code and recompile; if it still fails, repeat. When it doesn't fail, either you'll recognize what's wrong, or you can back up to the last one that failed and analyze it further.

Answer (score 1):

strcmp expects cstrings which you can get by going

```
std::string x = "blah blah";
assert(strcmp(x.c_str(), x.c_str()) == 0);
```

but if you're using std::strings anyways why not just use std::string::compare

```
std::string x = "blah blah";
assert(x.compare(x) == 0);
```

http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/compare/

caveat: if you're trying to do compare unicode strings then simple strcmp might not always work